# Can I fix a hard drive that fell on the floor and started making a nasty grinding noise?

Tags: hard-drive, repair

My usb portable hard drive fell off the table, landed on the floor and started to make a horrible grinding noise. I assume the platters fell off the spindle? (I think i'm making these terms up)

If i open it up (seagate barracuda) would i be able to salvage anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever your issue is, it sounds like a mechanical one.  Those sounds are coming from the drive itself, not the enclosure its in.

You, my friend, are out of luck.  Just to be sure, take the drive out of the enclosure and plug it into a PC.  If loud noises persist and you are unable to access it, then expensive data recovery services are your only hope (in many cases this route is VERY expensive)

Comment: I eventually opened it up, the platter was loose, it had broken off the spindle when it fell on the floor. Nice to have a look around inside though.

Answer (score 4):

No!
If you open a hdd you'll lose all data unless you send it to some fancy data recovery lab and that costs *[oodles](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/oodles) of money*.

Your best bet is to backup your data as quickly as possible.

The only thing you **might** be able to salvage is the external chassis the hdd is in. But even that will probably require some soldering.

Comment: i can definitely salvage the chassis, it's just got a ide to usb converter in it. AS to backing up the data - no chance, the platter is just rattling around inside the drive casing

Answer (score 0):

take the drive out of the container and see if you can get to the data if you plug it directly into the computer (ide or sata)

if you can you should run a program called spinrite on it and that will hopefully recover any damage.

if you can't see the drive then it might be pretty screwed some hdd have glass platers on the inside that can bust into a million pieces.